# Concrete roof weight holding capacity

Tags: concrete, roof

How much weight a concrete roof of 12x06 feet dimensions can hold. Will it easily support a water tank of 150 gallon capacity ?

Comment: How thick is the roof?

Comment: How much rebar ? Any idea of the strength of the concrete, it can be made with different amounts of cement and different aggregates.

Comment: depends on what is holding up the roof

Comment: This is heavily dependant on the the mix of the concrete and wetness of the concrete at pouring, proper vibrating and placing.  I wouldn't want to walk under it without alot of ignorance and hope.

Answer (score 2):

Well, basing the calcs on water, that is around 568kg or 1253lbs plus the weight of the tank itself and any associated pipework. Whether or not it will support such a load depends on the thickness of the concrete and whether or not it has any reinforcement.

Adding weight to a basically suspended slab increases the tension on the concrete and generally, concrete is weak in tension (unless reinforced).